# Is there a way to hide Steam tags?

Tags: steam

I do NOT want to hide games marked by those tags. I want to hide the tags themselves.

Some tags are too broad in my opinion and appear on many hardly related games. Some cover distinction I will hardly ever care about. But being popular, they push out of view other tags that I'd like to see - at least in discovery queue, but maybe in other places in UI too.

So, can I somehow hide some tags to give way for other tags to display?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to ignore or "skip" tags inside the Steam store.

In a browser, you *could* install an extension that will modify the content of a page and visually remove a tag from the page, but you will not get an additional tag to replace it.